# how to fix application for multiple screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

i have created an application in 2.2 version, if i run it in normal phone it works fine. but in tablet still it works fine but the label, textveiw and other things remain in the same size of the mobile phone.

I have used this code but its is not working.

```
<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Is their any other wayto do so, that my application look good in tablet tooo.

my xml code, and i am using it inside table layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:background="#ffffff" android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical" 
  >
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header_login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView  android:id="@+id/login_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingBottom="5px"
            android:paddingLeft="3px"
            android:paddingTop="5px"
            android:src="@drawable/sap_new" />
    </RelativeLayout>

 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/login1" >
        </ImageView>
    <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="15px" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
         <TextView android:text="Username " android:layout_column="0" android:textColor="#000000" android:id="@+id/usrLbl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="right" />
        <TextView android:text="" android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="left" android:width="20dip" android:textColor="#FF0000" /> 
        <EditText android:id="@+id/sapuser" android:hint="Required"
            android:layout_column="2" android:width="150dip" android:paddingLeft="5dip"
             android:layout_marginRight="15dip" android:text="" android:singleLine="true" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:gravity="center"  android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:text="Password " android:layout_column="0" android:textColor="#000000"
             android:gravity="right" android:id="@+id/passLbl" />
        <TextView android:text="" android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="left" android:textColor="#FF0000" /> 
        <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:hint="Required"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:layout_column="2"
             android:password="true" android:text=""
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_marginRight="15dip"   />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:gravity="center"  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_column="0"
             android:gravity="right"  />
        <TextView android:text="" android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="left" android:textColor="#FF0000" /> 
    <CheckBox
          android:id="@+id/ShowPassword"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:text="Show Password" android:textColor="#000000" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" /> 
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:gravity="center"  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_column="0"
             android:gravity="right"  />
        <TextView android:text="" android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="left" android:textColor="#FF0000" /> 
    <CheckBox
          android:id="@+id/SavePassword"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:text="Save Password" android:textColor="#000000" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" android:button="@drawable/checkbox" /> 
    </TableRow>
    <LinearLayout android:paddingTop="10px" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Login"
                android:gravity="center"  />





    </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use match parent or wrap content instead of setting static values for height and width

Comment: ya, i am using match parent or wrap content, either the problem is that i m using it inside table layout.

Comment: so what size you have specified for table row?
if possible post the xml where you have written code for table layout

Comment: the code was to length, so i deleted few items inside table layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create value/dimens.xml file for mobile and value-sw600dp/dimes.xml for tablet. Next you should write down there different dimensions for each item in your layout. Like this:

File values/dimens.xml :

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="sapuser_width">150dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

File values-sw600dp/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="sapuser_width">300dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

After that you should write down references on dimensions. For example

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/sapuser" android:hint="Required"
            android:layout_column="2" android:width="@dimen/sapuser_width" android:paddingLeft="5dip"
             android:layout_marginRight="15dip" android:text="" android:singleLine="true" />
```

Note that for 7 inch and 10 inch you should use different values:

- For 7 inch - values-sw600dp
- For 10 inch - values-sw720dp

Comment: it set to the values/dimens.xml only,

Comment: i am using 2.2 vwersion, and values-sw600dp works above3.2 versions

Answer (score 2):

Don't set view's size or text's size in `px`.
Use `dp`.

Check the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: I think for view size's use dp or dip & for text size's use sp.